# Change class of Body if Slider Class is active / visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, webflow

I have a Webflow Slider (which may be irrelevant to the task) and need to change the class of the 'body' if a particular slide with class 'switch-nav' is present. Currently I've tried various methods and many will add the body class initially, but will not remove it when the slider with the 'switch-nav' class goes out of view / we move to the next slide that does not have that class. This is the general slide markup:-

```
<div class="slide switch-nav w-slide" style=transform: translateX(-4500px); opacity: 1; visibility: hidden;"></div>
<div class="slide image-2 w-slide" style="transform: translateX(-4500px); opacity: 1; z-index: 1; visibility: hidden;"></div>
<div class="slide image-3 w-slide" style="transform: translateX(-4500px); opacity: 1; z-index: 3; transition: opacity 800ms; -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms;"></div>
```

Ideally this will trigger whether the class is in the viewport or not as I am looking to change the 'page' navigation via the class switch.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've tried it yet, but jQuery has a visibility selector.

```
if $('.switch-nav').is(":visible") {
    $(this).addClass('visibleClass');
}
else {
    $(this).removeClass('visibleClass');
}
```

Comment: Hi yeah I have tied that, with no avail. I think it may be soemthing to do with how the webflow slider animates in the slide with:- transition: opacity 800ms; -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms; which means that the script is not triggering....

Comment: also as I understand it the 'visible' selector is looking for the 'display' property and in this case its 'visibility' and not 'display'.